# If I promote someone as a leader will I still be a leader also?

Tags: king-of-thieves

I'm playing King of Thieves and I'm a guild leader. I wanted to know if I promote someone will I still be the leader?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information given in the King of Thieves forum and help, you can transfer leadership to somebody else but there cannot be two co-leaders. In simpler terms, if you promote somebody to leader, you won't be leader anymore.

Update: an update to the guild system will introduce a "second-in-command" to the guild, which can kick people.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there can be only one leader in a guild at any time. You would be transferring the leadership to somebody else, not sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one leader at a time and according to [Zeptolab Support](https://zepto.helpshift.com/a/king-of-thieves/?s=guilds-guild-battles&f=who-is-a-guild-leader)
the only way to regain leadership is if you get the new leader to transfer leadership back to you.